# Python Popen running batch file but not executing python for some reason

Tags: python, batch-file, subprocess, fastapi, popen

I'm trying to run a **subprocess** using **subprocess.Popen** through a **batch file**. When I run the batch file through the cmd it works fine. But - when I run it through the python code it executes the subprocess and does everything in the batch file but the python program that is supposed to run from the batch file doesn't seem to work.

The FastAPI endpoint:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)

@app.post("/projects/{project_name}/run")
async def run_project(project_name: str, action: Action):
    # Update the "reprocess_all" value field in the general.yaml file:
    val = dict(action)['reprocess_all']
    update_general_config(project_name, {'reprocess_all': val})
    global bg_process
    return await bg_process.run_process_project(project_name,
                                                dict(action)['action'],
                                                dict(action)['selected_import_sets'])
```

The bg_process.run_process_project():

```
async def run_process_project(self, project_name, action, selected_import_sets):
    if action == 'start':
        if self.processing_is_running:
            return {'status': 'failed', 'error': 'already running', 'project_name': self.processing_project}
        # ok, we can run. Create the thread to run the actual processing

        # Update the 'do_process' property in the instructions.yaml:
        self.update_do_process_properties(project_name, selected_import_sets)

        Thread(target=self.run_process_project_thread, args=(project_name, self.websocket_queue)).start()

        broadcaster_task = asyncio.create_task(self.message_broadcaster())
        await broadcaster_task

        return {'status': 'OK'}

def run_process_project_thread(self, project_name, websocket_queue):
    # mark started
    self.lock.acquire()
    self.processing_status_update(run_stat=True, project_name=project_name)
    self.lock.release()
    print("Hey Tal")
    proc = subprocess.Popen(
        [fr'C:\ProgramData\axioma\gpt\run_process.bat', fr'C:\ProgramData\axioma\gpt\Projects\TalTest']
    )
```

The batch file content:

```
set PYTHONPATH=c:\GPT\lib 
c:\GPT\gptenv\Scripts\python.exe c:\GPT\gis\test2.py >> c:\tmp\logs.txt
```

The output through the cmd:
[image]

When I run it through the python code it runs the batch file **but not the test2.py code.**

**Edit:**

- I forgot to mention that the code does not work only from a FastAPI endpoint. Therefore here is the code inside the function:
- Iv'e added the code running the Popen line.

Comment: Try: `["cmd.exe", "/k", fr'C:\ProgramData\axioma\gpt\run_process.bat', fr'C:\ProgramData\axioma\gpt\Projects\TalTest']`

Comment: @MauriceMeyer That doesn't seem to work. I've updated the post noting that the code doesn't do the job only from a FastAPI endpoint.

Comment: Have you tried passing the infamous `Shell=True` parameter to `subprocess.Popen`?

Comment: Yes I tried that and it didn't work. @Friedrich

Comment: This is probably an environment problem. You should add the command `set` into your batch and search for the differences when launched from the command line and from the FastAPI handler.

Comment: On a side note, please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804) to understand the difference between `async def` and `def` in FastAPI

Comment: @Chris Iv'e added the code lines so you can see. As for the enviroment variables - there is a set to the PYTHONPATH for the enviroment variable. Is there another env variable that I should add?

Comment: @Tl2: If I had known what the problem was exactly, I would have posted an answer... I just advised you to do what I would have done first if I was facing that problem.

Comment: @SergeBallesta The same code works on another computer so I guess the problem is with my local computer.